# Как создать рабочий url без создания html (php) документа?

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Во многих интернет-магазинах замечаю, что url страницы товара является латинским транслитом наименования этого товара. И вряд-ли разработчики создают страницы под каждый из десятков тысяч товаров. Я видел решения с # после урла, с get хвостами, но это все не то. Подскажите пожалуйста новчику, как это реализуется? В чем отличие от стандартного метода создания страницы? И возможно ли такие "сгенерирлванные" страницы продвигать в Seo?

Comment: Что-то я не понял вопроса. Обрабатывают url в каком-нибудь php-скрипте да и всё

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Интерпретацией адресов страниц, как сказано выше, занимается сервер и
>   программное обеспечение сайта. Для каждой серверной реализации есть
>   собственный модуль, реализующий подобную функциональность.
>
> На сервере IIS такая функциональность реализуется бесплатным модулем
>   «URLRewriter». В то же время для сервера Apache существует модуль
>   «mod_rewrite», который настраивается через файл .htaccess.
>
> Например, указав следующий код, веб-мастер сможет в PHP через массив
>   $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] получать все переданные параметры, а точкой
>   входа по любому запросу будет index.php[26].

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L,QSA]
```

[Семантический URL](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_URL#%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%85)

Comment: Благодарю, помогло! Правда пришлось повозиться долго)

Answer (score 1):

В базе у таблицы товаров, у каждого товара, к примеру, может быть поле - alias или url. Потом в бэкэнде разработчик пишет экшн контроллера, где принимается параметр - этот самый url или алиас и делается запрос в БД - если товар с такой меткой находится, то вытаскивается и под него рендерится страница.

Все это делается легко на php-фреймворках, самые популярные это YII2, Laravel. Там можно прописывать свои правила роутинга, вместо id товара подставляют этот самый алиас и все ок. И конечно же, такие страницы легко продвигать в поисковых системах, ибо сервер возвращает обычный html.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. В целом так и получилось брать сгенарисованный урл и вытаскивать из него категории, но без фреймворков. Помог mod_rewrite

Comment: Не подскажете, есть ли какие то особые требования и ньюансы продвижения таких 'фейковых' страниц в Seo?